# Haskell list type conversion

Tags: haskell

Support I have a list of type [Char], and the values enclosed are values of a different type if I remove their quotations which describe them as characters. e.g. ['2','3','4'] represents a list of integers given we change their type.

I have a similar but more complicated requirement, I need to change a [Char] to [SomeType] where SomeType is some arbitrary type corresponding to the values without the character quotations.

Comment: Check out the haskell tag info section for references to hoogle, and other resources that will help you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some function `foo :: Char -> SomeType`, you just need to map this function over your list of `Char`.

```
bar :: [Char] -> [SomeType]
bar cs = map foo cs
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get this correctly and there is a way (if the data-constructors are just one-letters too) - you use the auto-deriving for `Read`:

```
data X = A | B | Y
  deriving (Show, Read)

parse :: String -> [X]
parse = map (read . return)
```

(the `return` will just wrap a single character back into a singleton-list making it a `String`)

#### example

```
λ> parse "BAY"
[B,A,Y]
```